# Aws How to know the region of the Bucket using Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I using the following code to get the `listBuckets()`,

```
        AmazonS3ClientBuilder s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1");
        AmazonS3 s3Client = s3.build();
        bucketList = s3Client.listBuckets();
```

There are two things here:

1. It returns the list of all the Buckets present, irrespective of the region.
2. Each item of `bucketList()` which is a `Bucket` contains only these attributes:

```
bucket.getName()
bucket.getOwner()
bucket.getCreationDate()
```

It contains no *field/method* which can provide which region it lies in.

Also, when I try to get the count of `Objects` in this bucket using

```
s3Client.listObjectsV2(bucket.getName()).getKeyCount())
```

I get the following Exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket is in this region: us-east-2. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect;
```

I completely understood the error, but I need help with all of the following things:

- How to `listBuckets()` for a specific region only, without creating an `s3Client` for every region. Let's say my `s3Client` is of `us-east-1`, how do I get a list of all the buckets in region `ap-south-1`.
- How do I know the region of every bucket present in the `listBucket()` response as there are only `name, owner, and creation date` attributes.
- How do I get list of `Objects` of some another region using s3Client of some another region.

I guess it has something to do with `headers`.

Also a bonus help (or else I will have to ask another question)

- While downloading and uploading of objects, how can I display the progress of Upload/ Download of object, let's say my file size is 3GB, I need a way to show that 50% or a half filled progress bar perhaps to show 1.5GB is uploaded/downloaded.

Comment: @mokugo-devops Mah man, In need of your help again :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to filter a specific request of `ListBuckets` to a specific region as the request is built to list all buckets available to you as a user.

However, once you have retrieved the S3 buckets you can pass the `Name` of each bucket into the function [getBucketLocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getBucketLocation-java.lang.String-) called from the `S3Client`.

By doing this you'll be returned the region code.

The reason for this process is that S3 buckets are treated as a Global Service, each buckets name is unique irrespective of region. It just so happens you select which region the local data will exist.

Comment: Also how Do i call `s3Client.listObjectsV2(bucket.getName()).getKeyCount())` from the same S3Client providing another region. Or creating another S3Client/ changing it's region is the only option?

Comment: You'd need to set https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#setRegion-java.lang.String-

Comment: Also, can you please provide some pointers for the bonus question regarding progress above? If you suggest, I can ask another question for that too :)

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html

Comment: When I use `getBucketLocation`, it says  "The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2' (Service: Amazon S3..."

Since I cannot give a correct region, how can I get region info with this function?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I'll add to Chris William's correct answer that this method might not work with cross-account bucket access. In those cases, creating an s3 client in a region different than that of the bucket on the other account will result in a redirect response/error when trying to call `headBucket`, and an error when trying to call `getBucketLocation`.

The only way I could find for looking up the bucket region even cross account, is calling `headBucket` and using the redirect response header to figure out the correct region as follows:

```
    S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder().build();
    HeadBucketRequest req = HeadBucketRequest.builder().bucket("aicore-segmenter").build();

    try {
        HeadBucketResponse res = s3.headBucket(req);
    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        if (e.statusCode() == 301) {
            String newRegionName = e.awsErrorDetails().sdkHttpResponse().headers().get("x-amz-bucket-region").get(0);
            Region newRegion = Region.of(newRegionName);
        }
    }
```